# Fitting a line or polynomial to optical and radio SEDs

Tags: photometry, radio, active-galaxy

I've been trying to fit functions to plots showing photometric data for AGN from both optical and radio measurements, such as:

[image]

but my supervisor says that this shouldn't be done; the radio and optical components must be treated separately. Why is this?

Comment: Eyeballing it, it looks like different lines would fit the radio and optical parts...  OB xkcd https://xkcd.com/2048/

Comment: The two components are caused by two different physical mechanisms — synchrotron radiation from the jet, and the revolving material in the accretion disk , respectively — so there's no reason they should transition smoothly from one to the other.